# How do I get a cylinder to unwrap to a circle instead of rectangles?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I downloaded a model from turbosquid and needed to simplify some of it.  In the process I simply lopped off the complicated bits (a gear edge) and extruded a nice smooth edge.  Now I need to get that edge to match the texture provided with the model and it won't unwrap into a circle again.  Ive tried smart uv, cube, cylinder, sphere, and project from view with no luck.

I'm sure there is probably some fast super nifty way to do this, or to even smooth out that gear edge but decimate was producing messy results and I tried to merge by distance but again, messy.  Aside from going vertice by vertice and moving each one I couldn't think of a way to get rid of it w/o just cutting it off.  Any tips, tricks, or help would be appreciated.  I tried to do some youtube/google searches but it seems people want to go the other way.

[image: ge]

Comment: When you did project from view, did you align your view directly "above" it first? (Presuming that is the correct angle)

Comment: Thanks Christopher!  I ended up separating that piece so I could change the origin and align it properly then after fiddling with the view a bit I was able to get the desired result.  Thanks again!